# perform google sheets api access with android GoogleSignInApi credentials

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I know that there are several posts discussing signin/oauth for android but none of them solves my problem.

I am struggling to reconcile the auth flow with the GoogleSignInApi with the use of AccountManager in the google sheets v4 tutorial.

Using the GoogleSignInApi I end up with an authcode. So far so good. Next the docs recommend to exchange the authcode for an authtoken/recovery token. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access has a great example of how to send the auth code to the backend for exchange.

The only problem with this flow - I don't have my own backend as I just want to access the google sheets api. The sheets api call expects a GoogleCredential object which I cannot get from the authcode or otherwise via GoogleSignInAccount object.

So, my questions:

1. Where can I send the authcode which I received via GoogleSignInApi
   to have it exchanged for an authtoken.
2. Is there a library that handles the exchange request and refresh
   magic or am i expected to catch the refresh token and issue another
   auth token request myself.
3. Is there any better way to get the correct credentials for sheets
   access while also using the GoogleSignInApi for firebase services?
4. If I do end up using GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest as recommended
   for server side access, is it acceptable to use the client secret in
   the client? Probably not.

Here is a simplified version of the sheets api call I am trying to make.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken("TEST_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_OAUTH_PLAYGROUND");

mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                        transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                        .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API Android Quickstart")
                        .build();
```

UPDATE: To make some progress I ended up implementing a server side flow to exchange the token. I am pretty sure, this is not the right technique as it requires use of the client_secret in the app.

Part 1: SignInActivity is based on the firebase code lab. I need a firebase account so I feel that I have to use the GoogleSignInApi.

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {


    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    public static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    public static final String PREF_ID_TOKEN = "idToken";
    public static final String PREF_AUTH_CODE = "authCode";

    public static final Scope SHEETS_SCOPE = new Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.default_web_client_id));

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestScopes(SHEETS_SCOPE)
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult authResult) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.getEmail());
                editor.putString(PREF_ID_TOKEN, account.getIdToken());
                editor.putString(PREF_AUTH_CODE, account.getServerAuthCode());               
                editor.apply();

                // TODO: it would be great to do the exchange of the authcode now but it's doing a
                // network call and can't be on the main thread.

                // I really need this one
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Part 2: DataManager is a utility class which is used by the app to access sheets data. It doesn't use the flow recommended in the sheets code lab as that one doesn't allow me to set up the firebase account with the same user data.

```
public class DataManager {

    public static final String UNDEF = "undefined";

    private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService = null;
    // this is the play copy
    private static String mSheetID = SHEET_ID;

    private static final String PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN = "accessToken";
    private static final String PREF_REFRESH_TOKEN = "refreshToken";
    private static final String PREF_EXPIRES_IN_SECONDS = "expiresInSec";

    private Context mContext;
    private String mAccessToken;
    private String mRefreshToken;
    private Long mExpiresInSeconds;
    private String mAuthCode;

    public DataManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        mAuthCode = prefs.getString(SignInActivity.PREF_AUTH_CODE, UNDEF);
        mAccessToken =  prefs.getString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN, UNDEF);
        mRefreshToken = prefs.getString(PREF_REFRESH_TOKEN, UNDEF);
        mExpiresInSeconds = prefs.getLong(PREF_EXPIRES_IN_SECONDS, 0);
    }

    private void exchangeCodeForToken(String authCode) {

        try {
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                            new NetHttpTransport(),
                            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                            mContext.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id),
                            // TODO: the app shouldn't have to use the client secret
                            {CLIENT_SECRET},
                            authCode,
                            "")
                            .execute();

            mAccessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
            mRefreshToken = tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();
            mExpiresInSeconds = tokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds();

            // TODO: do I really need to store and pass the three values individually?
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN, mAccessToken);
            editor.putString(PREF_REFRESH_TOKEN, mRefreshToken);
            editor.putLong(PREF_EXPIRES_IN_SECONDS, mExpiresInSeconds);
            editor.remove(SignInActivity.PREF_AUTH_CODE);
            editor.apply();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Token exchange failed with " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void refreshAccessToken(String refreshToken) {
        try {
            // TODO: what to do here?
            throw new Exception("TBD");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Token refresh failed with " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private GoogleCredential getCredential() {

        if (mAuthCode != UNDEF) {
            exchangeCodeForToken(mAuthCode);
        }

        // TODO: handle missing or expired token
        if (mRefreshToken !=  UNDEF && mExpiresInSeconds < 30) {
            refreshAccessToken(mRefreshToken);
        }

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .build();
        credential.setAccessToken(mAccessToken);
        if (mRefreshToken !=  UNDEF) {
            credential.setRefreshToken(mRefreshToken);
            credential.setExpiresInSeconds(mExpiresInSeconds);
        }

        return credential;
    }

    // Set up credential and service object, then issue api call.
    public ArrayList<Foo> getFooListFromServer() throws IOException {
        try {
            GoogleCredential credential = getCredential();

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                   .setApplicationName(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();

            return getDataFromServer();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            // ...
            throw exception;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "something else is going on " + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actually fetch the data from google
     *
     * @return List of Foos
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private ArrayList<Foo> getDataFromServer() throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();

        ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(mSheetID, mRange)
                .setValueRenderOption("UNFORMATTED_VALUE")
                .setDateTimeRenderOption("FORMATTED_STRING")
                .execute(); 
        //...
        return foos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problems with credentials would easily be avoided if you use the [Android Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android).

Here are the steps mentioned in the guide:

```
Step 1: Acquire a SHA1 fingerprint
Step 2: Turn on the Google Sheets API
Step 3: Create a new Android project
Step 4: Prepare the project
Step 5: Setup the sample
```

The OAuth client ID is found in the [Google Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: I agree, the quickstart helps with sheets access and I got that working without problems. However, I also need to authenticate with firebase to use some of their components and the credentials the quickstart uses (GoogleAccountCredential) don't allow for that.
 
My original question was how to combine credentials from the sheets tutorial with those needed for the firebase tutorial (acquired there via GoogleSignInApi.)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late with this answer... but I just want to help everyone. After, RnD of 3 days, finally I ***found a working solution for Refresh token is null in oAuth Google via google sign in android***

Everyone using this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestScopes(SHEETS_SCOPE)
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

add one more parameter:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestScopes(SHEETS_SCOPE)
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id), true) //For offline access or background access token generation
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

> after this, you will get a server auth token, which returns the
>   refresh_token along with access_token